# Comparar datos de un input con registros en MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un input en HTML con AJAX el cual me ingresa un código de 4 dígitos con un botón de envío a una base de datos en MySQL, hasta el momento todo inserta perfectamente, y registra en la base de datos.

Ahora tengo que comparar ese dato que se ingresa en el input y cuando se de click en el botón de enviar, me compare ese dato en el input con todos los registros que tiene la base de datos, es decir si al comparar con todos los datos que tenga en la base de datos y encuentra uno igual me envíe un mensaje diciendo que ese dato ya se encuentra registrado en la base de datos de MySQL.

Para insertar los datos utilizo PHP. A continuación pongo el código que usé para insertar estos valores.

```
<?php

include('conectar.php');

if (isset($_POST['item']) && !empty($_POST['item'])) {

        $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db);
        mysqli_query($con,("INSERT INTO TablaCodigos(item) VALUES ('$_POST[item]')"));
        echo "<script> alert('Datos Ingresados correctamente a la base de datos') </script>"; 

} else {

    echo "<script> alert('Error!! No se han podido ingresar datos a  la base de datos') </script>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es un SELECT para consultar si lo que tienes en tu input ya está en el registro o no, te anexo un pequeño código de como lo haría, basándome en tu código expuesto, puede faltar un algo ya que no lo depuré pero la idea es esta:

```
<?php

include('conectar.php');     

if (isset($_POST['item']) && !empty($_POST['item'])) {
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db);

    //1 Hacer una consulta a la base de datos en tu tabla antes de registrar el registros       
    $item = $_POST['item']; 
    $dato =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT item FROM TablaCodigos WHERE item = '".$item."'");

    // Verifica si encontro al menos un registro..Contar el numero de filas 
    $duplicado = mysqli_num_rows($dato);

    if($duplicado==0){
        //Quiere decir que no se encontró un item igual a la del input entonces inserta
        mysqli_query($con,("INSERT INTO TablaCodigos(item) VALUES ('$_POST[item]')"));
        echo "<script> alert('Datos Ingresados correctamente a la base de datos') </script>"; 
        }else{
        echo "<script> alert('Item duplicado') </script>";
        }   
} else {

echo "<script> alert('Error!! No se han podido ingresar datos a  la base de datos') </script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

La manera para lograr eso es consultando en la base de datos si ese valor ya existe. Podrías hacerlo de este modo:

```
    if (isset($_POST['item']) && !empty($_POST['item'])) {

        $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db);
        mysqli_query($con,("INSERT INTO TablaCodigos (item) VALUES('$_POST[item]') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TablaCodigos WHERE item='$_POST[item]')LIMIT 1 "));

        if($mysqli->affected_rows){
              echo "<script> alert('Datos Ingresados correctamente a la base de datos') </script>"; 
        }else{
              echo "<script> alert('Datos no ingresados...') </script>";

    } else {

        echo "<script> alert('Error!! No se han podido ingresar datos a  la base de datos') </script>";
    }
```

`$mysqli->affected_rows;` Devuelve el numero de filas afectadas por la última consulta INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE.

La manera en la que se está ultilizando en el ejemplo es para verificar la cantidad de registros insertados. Pero si no es insertado no significará necesariamente que el registro no se insertó porque es duplicado de un dato almacenado